# Wrapper class for HttpGet / Post in Java?

Tags: java, http, httpwebrequest, http-post, http-get

Sorry, I'm quite new to Java.

I've stumbled across HttpGet and HttpPost which seem to be perfect for my needs, but a little long winded. I have written a rather bad wrapper class, but does anyone know of where to get a better one?

Ideally, I'd be able to do

```
String response = fetchContent("http://url/", postdata);
```

where postdata is optional.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to add, I'm not 'expecting' to be able to do it in one line. It's just an example - I realise Java is probably more precise and I will require try's and catch's for everything to work properly.

Comment: "Cannot instantiate the type HttpClient" - that's what I get when I try to use HttpClient for "HttpClient client = new HttpClient();"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) sounds like what you want. You certainly can't do stuff like the above in one line, but it's a fully-fledged HTTP library that wraps up Get/Post requests (and the rest).

Comment: If you end up doing anything real with it, you probably will require authentication/ssl (which HttpClient supports).

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/index.html) library.  From their [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html), you can generate a POST like this:

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://jakarata.apache.org/");
NameValuePair[] data = {
  new NameValuePair("user", "joe"),
  new NameValuePair("password", "bloggs")
};
post.setRequestBody(data);
// execute method and handle any error responses.
...
InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
// handle response.
```

There are a number of advanced options for configuring the client should you eventually required those.